# Can two GIN indexes on the same table cause performance degradation?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, full-text-search

I have the following query (postgresql):

```
select prt.a,
(SELECT count(ind.b) FROM ind WHERE ind.indexed_field_1 @@ to_tsquery(prt.a)
AND lower(ind.t) not in ('a', 'b', 'c')) cnt
from p as prt
order by cnt desc
limit 200;
```

`ind.indexed_field_1` is indexed with a GIN index. So far so good - it runs roughly for ~1 sec (ind has ~600K rows).

Once I add `indexed_field_2` to `ind` table, and index it with GIN index - the original query suddenly runs for ~5 seconds, and the same goes for a similar query on the `indexed_field_2`:

```
select prt.a,
(SELECT count(ind.b) FROM ind WHERE ind.indexed_field_2 @@ to_tsquery(prt.a)
AND lower(ind.t) not in ('a', 'b', 'c')) cnt
from p as prt
order by cnt desc
limit 200;
```

Any clues what can cause this?

The execution plans looks the same.

**EDIT**:

Execution plan for the 2nd query:

```
[
  {
    "Execution Time": 4863.615,
    "Planning Time": 0.3,
    "Plan": {
      "Startup Cost": 383480149.03,
      "Shared Hit Blocks": 1296773,
      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Read Blocks": 267565,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
          "Sort Key": [
            "((SubPlan 1)) DESC"
          ],
          "Node Type": "Sort",
          "Sort Space Used": 46,
          "Shared Hit Blocks": 1296773,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
              "Shared Hit Blocks": 1296773,
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Partial Mode": "Simple",
                  "Node Type": "Aggregate",
                  "Strategy": "Plain",
                  "Shared Hit Blocks": 1296773,
                  "Subplan Name": "SubPlan 1",
                  "Plans": [
                    {
                      "Exact Heap Blocks": 1383693,
                      "Node Type": "Bitmap Heap Scan",
                      "Shared Hit Blocks": 1296773,
                      "Plans": [
                        {
                          "Startup Cost": 0,
                          "Plan Width": 0,
                          "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                          "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                          "Shared Read Blocks": 5872,
                          "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                          "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
                          "Index Cond": "(indexed_field_2  @@ to_tsquery(prt.a)",
                          "Plan Rows": 3156,
                          "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                          "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                          "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                          "Parallel Aware": false,
                          "Actual Rows": 51,
                          "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                          "Total Cost": 43.68,
                          "Shared Hit Blocks": 173739,
                          "Actual Loops": 44742,
                          "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                          "Index Name": "part_ids2_idx"
                        }
                      ],
                      "Shared Read Blocks": 266531,
                      "Relation Name": "ind",
                      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                      "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                      "Plan Width": 16,
                      "Actual Loops": 44742,
                      "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
                      "Lossy Heap Blocks": 0,
                      "Filter": "(lower(ind.t) <> ALL ('{a,b,c}'::text[]))",
                      "Alias": "ind",
                      "Recheck Cond": "(indexed_field_2  @@ to_tsquery(prt.a)",
                      "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                      "Startup Cost": 44.46,
                      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                      "Plan Rows": 3109,
                      "Parallel Aware": false,
                      "Actual Rows": 51,
                      "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                      "Total Cost": 8563.06,
                      "Rows Removed by Filter": 0
                    }
                  ],
                  "Shared Read Blocks": 266531,
                  "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                  "Plan Width": 8,
                  "Actual Loops": 44742,
                  "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Startup Cost": 8570.83,
                  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Plan Rows": 1,
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Actual Rows": 1,
                  "Parent Relationship": "SubPlan",
                  "Total Cost": 8570.84
                }
              ],
              "Shared Read Blocks": 267565,
              "Relation Name": "parties",
              "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
              "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
              "Plan Width": 24,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Alias": "parties",
              "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
              "Local Read Blocks": 0,
              "Startup Cost": 0,
              "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
              "Local Written Blocks": 0,
              "Plan Rows": 44742,
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Actual Rows": 44742,
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Total Cost": 383478215.31
            }
          ],
          "Shared Read Blocks": 267565,
          "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
          "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Sort Method": "top-N heapsort",
          "Plan Width": 24,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
          "Local Read Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
          "Startup Cost": 383480149.03,
          "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Sort Space Type": "Memory",
          "Local Written Blocks": 0,
          "Plan Rows": 44742,
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Actual Rows": 200,
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Total Cost": 383480260.89
        }
      ],
      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
      "Node Type": "Limit",
      "Plan Rows": 200,
      "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Actual Rows": 200,
      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
      "Plan Width": 24,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
      "Total Cost": 383480149.53
    },
    "Triggers": []
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

New indexes can change the optimizer's estimates and the execution plan chosen, and the new plan might (by accident) be worse than the old one.

That's all you can say without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for both queries.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the question and add the plans + execution times.